# Lighttpd, PHP, WordPress and permissions

Tags: php, permissions, wordpress, lighttpd

I'm wondering why WordPress isn't able to install or update themes and plugins. I can upload files thought. This is a permissions problem, even when I CHMOD 0777 on the wp-content/themes and wp-content/plugins directory it still doesn't work.

I know I've got something set up wrong, whether it's to do with my lighttpd set up or to do with the way I've set up permissions. I've checked lighttpd's conf and the user is www-data, however if I set CHOWN of the blog to www-data, I'm not able to edit the files through SSH.

So what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If chown'ing the files to www-data works, you can set it up with group permissions to still allow you (and other users, if necessary) to be able to edit the directories.  For example, you could add yourself to a group called 'developers' and then do `chown -R www-data:developers  .`.

Comment: Interesting, and (without sounding dumb) how can I a) set up the developers group and b) add myself and www-data to it?